# convert from double to strings

Tags: string, matlab, double

I have the matrix of double `A`

```
  A=[1 1 1 2 1;
     2 1 1 2 1;
     3 1 1 2 1;
     4 1 1 2 1;
     1 2 1 2 1;
     2 2 1 2 1;
     3 2 1 2 1;
     4 2 1 2 1];
```

and I want to convert it in a matrix of string `B`

```
B= {'11121';
    '21121';
    '31121';
    '41121';
    '12121';
    '22121';
    '32121';
    '42121'}.
```

To do this, I have tried to use `num2str` but I obtained `C` that inside every string have two spaces

```
C = {'1  1  1  2  1';
     '2  1  1  2  1';
     '3  1  1  2  1';
     '4  1  1  2  1';
     '1  2  1  2  1';
     '2  2  1  2  1';
     '3  2  1  2  1';
     '4  2  1  2  1'}
```

I don't know how to delete the spaces from `C`.

Comment: I'm adding this a comment because the other answers are probably better but you can easily just delete all the spaces in your `C` like this: `cellfun(@(s)s(s~=' '), C)`

Comment: @elis56 - just wondering - you say the input matrix is `double`, but in your example it contains single-digit integers. What are the actual values of the possible inputs? Will there be fractions, complex numbers etc.? Or are they always positive integers representing single digits?

Comment: If your strings are all the same length, why do you want a cell array? A normal char matrix would probably be faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this is to use [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) to convert the array to a long string of digits. You can then reshape this string into the appropriate shape. Then you can use [`cellstr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellstr.html) to convert each row of the reshaped string into a separate cell array element.

```
out = cellstr(reshape(sprintf('%d', A), [], size(A,2)));
```

**Explanation**

First convert the matrix into a long string of digits.

```
s = sprintf('%d', A)
%// 1234123411112222111111112222222211111111
```

Then we want to reshape this so that each row of numbers in the original is a row of numbers in the output

```
s = reshape(s, [], size(A,2))
%// 11121
%// 21121
%// 31121
%// 41121
%// 12121
%// 22121
%// 32121
%// 42121
```

Then we can use `cellstr` to convert each row of this into it's own cell array

```
out = cellstr(s);
%// '11121'
%// '21121'
%// '31121'
%// '41121'
%// '12121'
%// '22121'
%// '32121'
%// '42121'
```

## A different approach

Another way that you could accomplish this is to treat each column of `A` as a place value (i.e. 10000's place, 1000's, place, 100's place, etc.) and convert each row to an integer knowing that. This can easily be done by multiplying each row with an array of `10^(N-1:-1:0)` and summing the elements. This will yield a digit for each row that combines all of the columns. We can then use `num2str` to convert this to a cell array of strings.

```
%// Then convert each number to a string in a cell array
out = arrayfun(@num2str, A * (10.^(size(A, 2)-1:-1:0)).', 'uni', 0);
```

Or to shorten this even more, we can borrow a page out of [@rayryeng's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36747186/670206) book and use `sprintfc` to convert this array of integers into a cell array of strings:

```
out = sprintfc('%d', A * (10.^(size(A, 2)-1:-1:0)).');
```

## Benchmark

I was curious about the performance of the methods presented here and in [@rayryeng's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36747186/670206) and [Dev-iL's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36748374/670206) when you increase the number of rows. I wrote up a quick test script.

```
function tests()
    % Test the number of rows between 100 and 10000
    nRows = round(linspace(100, 10000, 100));

    times1 = zeros(numel(nRows), 1);
    times2 = zeros(numel(nRows), 1);
    times3 = zeros(numel(nRows), 1);
    times4 = zeros(numel(nRows), 1);
    times5 = zeros(numel(nRows), 1);

    %// Generate a random matrix of N x 5
    getRandom = @(n)randi([0, 9], [n, 5]);

    for k = 1:numel(nRows)
        A = getRandom(nRows(k));
        times1(k) = timeit(@()string_reshape_method(A));
        A = getRandom(nRows(k));
        times2(k) = timeit(@()base10_method(A));
        A = getRandom(nRows(k));
        times3(k) = timeit(@()sprintfc_method(A));
        A = getRandom(nRows(k));
        times4(k) = timeit(@()addition_method(A));
    end

    %// Plot the results
    plot(nRows, cat(2, times1, times2, times3, times4)*1000);
    legend({'String Reshape', 'Base-10 Conversion', 'sprintfc', 'addition of "0"'})

    xlabel('Number of Rows in A')
    ylabel('Execution Time (ms)');
end

function out = string_reshape_method(A)
    out = cellstr(reshape(sprintf('%d', A), [], size(A,2)));
end

function out = base10_method(A)
    out = sprintfc('%d', A * (10.^(size(A, 2)-1:-1:0)).');
end

function B = sprintfc_method(A)
    B = sprintfc(repmat('%d', 1, size(A,2)), A);
end

function B = addition_method(A)
    B = cellstr(char(A + '0'));
end
```

Here are the results.

[image]

Comment: @elis56 Be sure to checkout the updated post if you're interested in the performance of the different methods.

Comment: I have seen now the post: thanks to much for the plot and for suggestions :)

Answer (score 5):

My suggestion is this:

```
out = cellstr(char(A + '0'));
```

Basically what we do is add the ASCII value of `0` to your matrix then convert it to characters. I didn't benchmark it, but it should be comparably fast :)

Comment: This will only work for numbers less than `9` though

Comment: @Dan - thanks for pointing that out. I was too focused on the provided example...

Comment: @Dev-iL I think it's a fair assumption though, and the accepted `reshape` method probably also has this limitation

Answer (score 4):

How about using something undocumented?  We can see that you have 5 numbers per cell, or the total number of columns per cell.  As such, create a format string for like you'd use for `fprintf` with `%d` but duplicated for as many columns as you have in `A`, then use the undocumented function [`sprintfc`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/sprintfc-undocumented-helper-function) to do the conversion from number to cell in one shot:

```
s = repmat('%d', 1, size(A,2));
B = sprintfc(s, A);
```

## Example run

```
>> A=[1 1 1 2 1;2 1 1 2 1;3 1 1 2 1;4 1 1 2 1;1 2 1 2 1;2 2 1 2 1;3 2 1 2 1;4 2 1 2 1];
>> s = repmat('%d', 1, size(A,2));
>> B = sprintfc(s, A)

B = 

    '11121'
    '21121'
    '31121'
    '41121'
    '12121'
    '22121'
    '32121'
    '42121'
```

Comment: @Suever Hehe... hence it being worthy of the function being called undocumented :D. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Methods based on "clearing the spaces" from the `num2str` output:

**Method 1:**

```
cellfun(@(s)s(s~=' '), num2str(A));
```

**Method 2:**

```
regexprep(cellstr(num2str(A)),' ','');
```